# Scan destination for Epson Workforce Printer/Scanner

Tags: windows-7, printer, scanner, scanning, epson-workforce

For the Epson Workforce 3640 all-in-one printer/scanner/fax, how does one set the destination folder (Windows 7) for scans **originating from** the scanner.

*(It's easy to set the destination for scans when the scan request is originated from the computer... but this question is how to set the scan destination folder when the scan request is originated from the printer/scanner itself.)*

Answer (score 0):

Scanning to folder can be done from the Control Panel, as detailed on pg 67 of the [User's Guide](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd3/cpd39368.pdf)

Before you can use that, you need to set up the folder on the computer, and you have to add it to the printer's "Contact List". Again this can be done from the Control Panel, as explained on page 102 of the [User's Guide](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd3/cpd39368.pdf). You can add up to 100 email addresses, network folders, and fax numbers. Each entry is limited to 30 characters.

Although I have not found any details in the manual, the folder name should be of the format \PC_Name\Folder_name. After you create the folder on the PC, right-click it in Windows Explorer and go to Properties. Click the Sharing tab and the "Sharing" button. Select Everyone from the drop-down, and click "Add". Under "Permission Level", select "Read/Write" to make sure the scanner has permissions to create files.

Comment: Thank you. The Administrator's Manual is only 56 pages, so I can't find page 102. :-0  Can you help?

Comment: Sorry RockPaperLizard, I stuffed up my links and now I cannot find the manual that shows a picture of the control panel. But the User's Guide does give enough detail to set you straight, I hope.